# Password Errors with PHP sign up script

Tags: php, arrays, passwords

I am using a PHP Sign-Up  script provided by *PHP Form Generator*. There was a lot of obsolete code so I had to go in and fix it.

My problem is, the first test user I created worked completely fine, but all other test users I create end up having an unknown Array as the password.

This is the code:

```
<?php
    include("http://wolffwebdesign.co.cc/php/global.inc.php");
    $errors=0;
    $error="The following errors occured while processing your form input.<ul>";
    $FirstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FirstName']);
    $MiddleInitial = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['MiddleInitial']);
    $LastName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['LastName']);
    $Company = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Company']);
    $Email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);
    $Username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Username']);
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];
    $resultuser = mysql_query("SELECT Username FROM members WHERE Username = '$Username'");
    $resultpass = mysql_query("SELECT Password FROM members WHERE Password = '$Password'");

    if($FirstName=="" || $LastName=="" || $Company=="" || $Email=="" || $Username=="" || $Password=="" ){
        $errors=1;
        $error.="<li>You did not enter one or more of the required fields. Please go back and try again.</li>";
    }
    if(!preg_match('/^[a-z\d_\.\-]+@([a-z\d\-]+)(?:\.(?1))+$/i',$Email)){
        $error.="<li>Invalid email address entered</li>";
        $errors=1;
    }
    $regex = '~([^A-Z0-9]+)~i'
    if(!preg_match($regex, $Username) || !preg_match($regex, $Password)) {
        $errors.="<li>Invalid Username or Password entered</li>";
        $errors=1;
    }

    if($errors==1) {
        echo $error;
    }
    if(mysql_num_rows($resultuser) == 1){
         die("<li>That Username exists already</li>");
    }
    if(mysql_num_rows($resultpass) == 1){
       die("<li>That password exists already</li>");
    }
    else{
        if($remember == 1)
            {$expire=time()+50400;
            setcookie("extendedloginwwd", $Username, $expire);
        }
        elseif($remember == 0)
            {$expire=time()+50400;
            setcookie("loginwwd", $Username, $expire);
        }
        mkdir("home/wolffweb/www/$Username", 0755);
        $where_form_is="http".($HTTP_SERVER_VARS["HTTPS"]=="on"?"s":"")."://".$SERVER_NAME.strrev(strstr(strrev($PHP_SELF),"/"));
        mail( "wolffswebdesign@gmail.com", "New User Submission", "Name: $LastName, $FirstName, $MiddleInitial\nCompany: $Company\nEmail: $Email\nUsername: $Username\nPassword: $password\nFolder: $dirname\nErrors?: $error\n", "From: Sign Up <newuser@wolffwebdesign.x10.mx>" );
        $link = mysql_connect("localhost","wolffweb_admin","jl10101");
        mysql_select_db("wolffweb_users",$link);
        $query="insert into members (First_Name,Middle_Initial,Last_Name,Company,Email,Username,Password) values ('".$FirstName."','".$MiddleInitial."','".$LastName."','".$Company."','".$Email."','".$Username."','".$Password."')";
        mysql_query($query);
        $make=fopen("admin/data.dat","a");
        $to_put="";
        $to_put .= $FirstName."|".$MiddleInitial."|".$LastName."|".$Company."|".$Email."|".$Username."|".$Password."
        ";
        fwrite($make,$to_put);
    }
    ?>
```

This is the shown content:

```
<!-- This is the content of the Thank you page, be careful while changing it -->

    <h2>Thank you!</h2>

    <table width=50%>
        <tr>
            <td>
                First Name: 
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $FirstName; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Middle Initial: 
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $MiddleInitial; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Last Name: 
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $LastName; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Company: 
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $Company; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Email: 
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $Email; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Username: 
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $Username; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Password: 
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $Password; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<!-- Do not change anything below this line -->

<?php
{}
?>
```

If, for example, I made my password *hello52* where `<?php echo $Password; ?>` and also in the MYSQL Database the password ends up being the word *Array*, which when I plug *Array* in to the Log In form I get an incorrect password error. My assumption is that the password ends up being some sort of random array. Is there any way to fix this?

EDITS:

The following is the form code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://wolffwebdesign.co.cc/php/sign-up.php" method="post">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="1" style="border-collapse: collapse" border="#000066" width="95%" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#B5CBEF" height="17" width="100%" border="#FFFFFF" background="http://wolffwebdesign.co.cc/media/tile_back.gif">
                <p align="left" class="c1"><img border="0" src="nav_m.gif" width="8" height="8" alt="triangle"><strong>&nbsp;Sign Up&nbsp;</strong></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#B5CBEF" height="16" width="100%" border="#FFFFFF" background="http://wolffwebdesign.co.cc/media/tile_sub.gif">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#D6DFEF" height="16" width="100%" border="#FFFFFF">
                <p class="c2">* - Required</p>
                <p class="c2">+ - Alpha-Neumeric only(A-Z, a-z, 0-9)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30" width="55" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <img border="o" src="http://wolffwebdesign.co.cc/media/bc_new.gif" width="28" height="28" alt="triangle in a blue circle"
            </td>
            <td height="30" width="189" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <p class="c3">First Name</p>
            </td>
            <td height="30" width="294" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <p class="c5"><input type="text" name="FirstName" size="25">*</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30" width="55" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <img border="o" src="http://wolffwebdesign.co.cc/media/bc_new.gif" width="28" height="28" alt="triangle in a blue circle"
            </td>
            <td height="30" width="189" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <p class="c3">Middle Initial</p>
            </td>
            <td height="30" width="294" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <p class="c5"><input type="text" name="MiddleInitial" size="1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30" width="55" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <img border="o" src="http://wolffwebdesign.co.cc/media/bc_new.gif" width="28" height="28" alt="triangle in a blue circle"
            </td>
            <td height="30" width="189" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <p class="c3">Last Name</p>
            </td>
            <td height="30" width="294" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <p class="c5"><input type="text" name="LastName" size="25">*</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30" width="55" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <img border="o" src="http://wolffwebdesign.co.cc/media/bc_new.gif" width="28" height="28" alt="triangle in a blue circle"
                                </td>
            <td height="30" width="189" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <p class="c3">Company</p>
            </td>
            <td height="30" width="294" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <p class="c5"><input type="text" name="Company" size="25">*</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30" width="55" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <img border="o" src="http://wolffwebdesign.co.cc/media/bc_new.gif" width="28" height="28" alt="triangle in a blue circle"
            </td>
            <td height="30" width="189" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <p class="c3">Email</p>
            </td>
            <td height="30" width="294" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <p class="c5"><input type="text" name="Email" size="25">*</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30" width="55" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <img border="o" src="http://wolffwebdesign.co.cc/media/bc_new.gif" width="28" height="28" alt="triangle in a blue circle"
            </td>
            <td height="30" width="189" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <p class="c3">Username</p>
            </td>
            <td height="30" width="294" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <p class="c5"> input type="text" name="Username" size="20">*+</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30" width="55" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <img border="o" src="http://wolffwebdesign.co.cc/media/bc_new.gif" width="28" height="28" alt="triangle in a blue circle"
            </td>
            <td height="30" width="189" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <p class="c3">Password</p>
            </td>
            <td height="30" width="294" bgcolor="#EFF3F7" border="#FFFFFF">
                <p class="c5"> input type="password" name="Password" size="10">*+</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#B5CBEF" height="25" width="538" background="tile_sub.gif">
                <p align="center"><p class="c3"><input type="submit" value="Submit Form">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="reset" value="Reset Form"></font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

Also I am using the mkdir() function because I want each user to have their own directory which contains a service page, the directory is not being created, is there any way to fix this?
Thanks
--James

Comment: by the way your script is subjected to SQL injection. See http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: You should use `empty()` instead of `$var == ""`.

Comment: Can you show the code of your form as well?

Comment: This script as plenty of MySQL Injection! Add `mysql_real_escape_string()` to your `$_POST[]` data **EXCEPT PASSWORD**! This function will prevent MySQL injection...

Comment: Just to clarify @Frederick Marcoux. `$Username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Username']);`

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux, the passwords seem to be saved in plain text, so they should be escaped too. But it's better to use `sha1()` or something similar. Saving passwords in plain text is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!preg_match('~([^A-Z0-9]+)~i', $Username, $Password)) {
    $errors.="<li>Invalid Username or Password entered</li>";
    $errors=1;
}
```

The above code passes an array of `preg_match('~([^A-Z0-9]+)~i', $Username)` to $Password

Try:

```
$regex = '~([^A-Z0-9]+)~i'
if(!preg_match($regex, $Username) || !preg_match($regex, $Password)) {
    $errors.="<li>Invalid Username or Password entered</li>";
    $errors=1;
}
```

Comment: @Saurav You shouldn't have added that comment to my answer. It is not relevant in any way to what I have typed and should have been added to the question instead.

Comment: @SimonMayer Sorry.  It seems I added the comment to the wrong section. I'll remove it.